# formal way to expressing check out some place

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I am applying for a travel visa to Japan. I needed to fill out a form as the schedule of stay. On a specific date, I am supposed to say which tourist attractions and what sightseeing I will be doing when I stay there.

I thought I would use the word "check out" as in I would check out some places or tourist attractions. But the word is rather informal. Can you guys suggest some other more formal words?

Also how should I talk about my schedule colloquially outside of "I will check out xxx place"?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going as a tourist, I think the word "visit" would work well. Example: "Today I am going to visit Tokyo, and tomorrow I will visit Yokohama." Visit isn't what I would call "formal", but it should be very appropriate for such a form. Visit should also be fine for speaking of your activities informally. Also, you can say, "I will **travel to** whatever city or place you intend to go to. If you would go into more detail about what you're going to be doing, it would help others to give you suggestions. What are you going to be doing? Sailing? Fishing? Visiting museums?

Comment: Mostly sightseeing. Can I use sightsee as a `verb`? as in, "I will sightsee at some park today". Also, is it weird to use "come to" when referring to the places I want to visit when I am already in that country. e.g. "I will come to some park today"?

Comment: Sightsee is a verb, but I think to use it correctly you would need to say something like, "I will go sightseeing at the city park today."  Or you could say, "I am seeing the sights downtown today." Using "come to" would be incorrect and sound bad. Use "go to" instead. "I am going to city park today."

Answer (score 1):

I agree with **Don B.** that your best bets for more formal phrasing are "visit" and "travel to".

As for the second part of your question, any of the following sound natural in informal parlance:

> I'm going to (check out) / (go see) / (go out to) / (go look at)  ______.